# Automatic creation of active Yammer account for O365 user

Tags: azure, office365, yammer

I'm seeking a method of automatically provisioning an ‘active’ Yammer user account for a new O365 user account (and existing ones, as a once off), without requiring the user to ‘click the Yammer tile’ or otherwise login to Yammer.

The default process ([as articulated in this post](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Manage-Yammer-users-across-their-life-cycle-from-Office-365-6c4c8fff-6444-404a-bffc-f9da0bcc3039)) is:

1. The Office 365 admin creates a user in Office 365 (or Azure AD).
2. The user logs on to Office 365 using the identity provider that is configured for the tenant.
3. The user clicks the Yammer tile in the app launcher to go to Yammer.
4. A new Yammer user is created for the Office 365 user.
5. The user's profile properties from Azure Active Directory are automatically populated in the user's Yammer profile.

We're building an employee app, which currently displays company news. We wish to add social functionality, leveraging the Yammer platform, via the REST API. We have developed a solution to impersonate existing users and like/comment on behalf their behalf.

However, most employees are ‘unsophisticated’ blue-collar workers, and it is anticipated that they will not complete steps 2, 3 & 4 above to ‘create/activate’ their Yammer user account (the **activation steps**).

Methods considered or explored so far:

1. Using the REST API to create a new user – this creates a user in the ‘pending’ state, which remains pending until the activation steps are completed.
2. Using the Bulk Update Users to create new users from a CSV:
   a) If a password is set, then a new ‘active’ user is successfully created (great!). However, that user account appears to be entirely disconnected from the corresponding O365 user account (meaning changes to user profile properties will not sync to/from Azure AD, passwords may be different, and users who are deleted/suspended in AAD will not sync to Yammer). These accounts are only linked if/when the activation steps are completed.
   b) If a password is not set, then the new user is created in a ‘pending’ state, much the same as using the REST API.

Questions:

- Is there any other way to create an 'active' user in Yammer, which is linked to the user’s O365 account?
- Could a provider hosted app be used to impersonate a user and complete the activation steps on their behalf?
- Not that it solves the problem, but does the REST API allow you to update a user’s state from 'pending' to 'active' (or create an 'active' user in the first place)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps about the default process are pretty acurate but I would add that once a user is created in AD users can simply go to Yammer.com (either on web or on iphone/android) and sign in through there. Iphone and Android use an Azure Authentication library that will find the users Office account.

Is there any other way to create an 'active' user in Yammer, which is linked to the user’s O365 account?
There isn't at this time.

Could a provider hosted app be used to impersonate a user and complete the activation steps on their behalf?
This isn't supported at this time.

Not that it solves the problem, but does the REST API allow you to update a user’s state from 'pending' to 'active' (or create an 'active' user in the first place)?
There is not an api for this.